# Non USB iPhone Charger

Tags: iphone, charger, lightning

Does anybody know of any non-USB chargers for iPhone (lightning connector)? I need a charger that can only plug into an AC outlet and not have any type of USB connector.

Comment: what did you find so far?

Comment: There are some that do this that plug into a DC outlet, but every AC charger I've seen is some variation of the charger the device ships with (i.e. a lightning to USB cable that plugs into a brick that plugs into an AC outlet

Comment: That is all I found so far (AC- USB out- Lightning end) so why no USB?

Comment: so you need hard wired version :)

Comment: Can you just permanently glue the USB into the socket with epoxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this a BH in a 20 second google search!
http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=902893&gclid=CJ6GgZrLkcMCFWFp7AodCg4AzQ&Q=&is=REG&A=details

Answer (score 2):

OK, if for "Edward Snowden" reason you can not use any USB connection in your work place, there is a alternative solution:

It is a 2 piece set that allows you to charge you phone in the car and in the office for $25 total.

1- Get a car charger to lightning [like this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FK6G59O)

2- get a car charger to wall adapter. [Like this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/230649818692?lpid=82&chn=ps).